# Как правильно прописать правило в urlManager для пагинации submodule?

Tags: php, yii2

Выдаёт ссылку такого вида `site.ru/module/submodule/default/index?page=2`,
а нужно `site.ru/submodule/?page=2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вроде так

```
'module/submodule/default/<_c:[\w\-]+>' => 'submodule/<_c>',
```

Нет примера протестировать, но суть такая
вам нужно прописать жестко правило, поскольку у вас какая ситуация
модуль\вложенныймодуль\контроллер\экшен а вы хотите  модуль = вложенный модуль\экшен
без контроллера и одного модуля

значит у нас динамически толлько экшен в контроллере default , мы его и выносим псевдонимом, остальное прописуем жестко

'moscow => russia/moscow/default/index'

Comment: Это не помогает, никак не реагирует...

Comment: а вы по какому url заходите? правильно в начале прописано?

Comment: submodul moscow так перехожу работает http://test.ru/moscow, тут есть пагинации выбераю 2 и ссылка образуется такого вида http://test.ru/russia/moscow/default/index?page=2 , а нужно так чтоб было http://test.ru/moscow/?page=2

Comment: module russia, есть submodulе moscow

Comment: отредактировал , пробуйте

Comment: почему то не реагирует странно

Comment: может нужно прописать page/<page>

Comment: вернее страницу не находит при переходе 2 и ссылка такая же  test.ru/russia/moscow/default/index?page=2

Comment: как же это решить

Comment: может тут что то сделать 
                        <?php
                        echo \yii\widgets\LinkPager::widget([
                            'pagination' => $pages,
                            ]);
                        ?>

Comment: зайдите без гет параметра- работает? зайдите туда же но с любым гет параметром. что теперь?

Comment: работает оно и до этого работала

Comment: только при переходе пагинации 2 ссылка становится такого вида test.ru/russia/moscow/default/index?page=2 мне не нужно хотя бы чтобы /russia/ в ссылке не выводилось

Comment: хотя бы так test.ru/moscow/default/index?page=2

Comment: так уберите, яж написал что за что отвечает, переделайте как вам нравится.  при пагинации перехеодит на старый адресс, потомучто ссылка не правильно построена

Comment: из-за russia картинки тоже не выводятся

Comment: пользуйтесь алиасами, чтоб картники не ехали

Comment: да с картинками разобрался

Comment: добавил 'russia/moscow/default/index' => 'moscow',  Not Found (#404)

Comment: что то ещё не хватает